# Intercept made by the curve

Tags: integration, differential-geometry

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to R$ be a continuous,strictly increasing function such that $f^5(x)=\int_0^xtf^4(t)dt$. If a normal is drawn to curve $y=f(x)$ with gradient $-\frac{1}{2}$, then the intercept made by it on the y-axis is k,then the value of $\frac{k}{3}$ is

MY APPROACH:

I used the leibniz integral rule and solved the equation to get $5f^4(x).f'(x)=xf^4(x)$
i.e. $f'(x)=\frac{x}{5}$.

Now for $y=f(x)$ gradient of normal will be given by $y=-\frac{1}{f'(x)}$

i.e. $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{5}{x}$ i.e. $x=10$ hence the intercept should be $10$ but it is an integer type question(answer has to be an integer) that proves me wrong.

Please HELP ME. THANKS

Comment: I want the value of $\frac{k}{3}$ which is not an integer(as k is the intercept i.e. $k=10$) hence i get the answer$3.33\ldots$

Comment: $x = 10$ is not the intercept, its the point from which normal would have the given slope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the equation of normal to find the intercept.

Realise that the $x=10$ is abscissa of the point from where you draw the normal. Its not the intercept.

We know the slope. We now have to find the point. For this, first find $f(x)$ by integration.

$$f(x) = \int \dfrac{x}{5}dx \\
 = \dfrac{x^2}{10}+C$$

To evaluate $C$, we use the first equality with $x = 0$:

$$f^5(x)= \int_0^x tf^4(t)dt =\left(\frac{x^2}{10}+C\right)^5$$

Put $x=0$ and you get $C = 0$

SO the point from which normal was drawn is $\frac{100}{10} = 10$

To find the normal, simply use slope ($\frac{-1}{2}$) and point $(10,10)$

$$y-10 = \frac{-1}{2}(x-10)$$

Put $x=0$ to get $y$-intercept, which comes out to be $15$

Comment: Ok but if we find the point it is again coming out to be $(10,0)$

Comment: You have to find intercept on y-axis!

Comment: Ok that means the point $(0,0)$. Hence answer should be $0$?

Comment: Please see edit :P

Comment: I am a little weak in straight lines and conic sections. :P